# Negate this statement

Tags: real-analysis, predicate-logic

$\exists \epsilon > 0: \forall\delta >0:\nexists x \in \left\lbrace x: |x-x_0|<\delta \right\rbrace : |x^2_0 - x^2| > \epsilon$

Have been having trouble with this, primarily because it appears really complicated.

Comment: The negation is: the function $x\mapsto x^2$ is continuous at $x_0$.

Comment: Take it one step at a time, from the outside. The negation of

$$\exists \epsilon > 0\; (P)$$ 

is

$$\forall \epsilon > 0, (\lnot P)$$

So now you need to negate$P$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\forall \epsilon > 0: \exists\delta >0:\neg(\nexists x \in \left\lbrace x: |x-x_0|<\delta \right\rbrace : |x^2_0 - x^2| > \epsilon)$$\equiv$ $\forall \epsilon > 0: \exists\delta >0:\exists x \in \left\lbrace x: |x-x_0|<\delta \right\rbrace : |x^2_0 - x^2| \leq \epsilon$

When you take the negation $\forall$ becomes $\exists$ and vice versa. And a statement like $\forall x: P(x)$ becomes $\exists x:\neg P(x)$.

Comment: Ahh thanks a lot